# dplyr mutate(). Problem with mutating one variable, in dependence on non-missing value in other columns matching specific names selected by matches()

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to mutate a variable, depending on the non-missing values in multiple other variables. There are variables, corresponding to the question were tests provided or not (let call them var_1), followed by the results of the tests (let call them var_1.1, var_1.2, var_1.3 etc). Logically, "No" s and "NA"s in the var_1 should mean "NA" s in var_1.1, var_1.2, var_1.3 etc, shouldn't they? But some observations, with "No" and "NA" in var_1, have non-missing values in var_1.1, var_1.2, var_1.3 etc. Therefore, I would like to mutate "No" and "NA" in var_1 into "Yes" for these observations. If you'll look at the figure it could be bit clearer what I want. Green-colored variables in var_1 represent correct values. Red-colored, bold-fonted variables are incorrect. 
Generally saying, I would like to shorten and make bit more elegant the following code:

```
df%>% mutate(var_1=ifelse(!is.na(var_1.1)| !is.na(var_1.2)| !is.na(var_1.3)| !is.na(var_1.4)| !is.na(var_1.n), "Yes", as.character(var_1))
```

Here are lines of code:
`df %>% mutate(var_1=if_else(!is.na(matches("var_1.")), "Yes", as.character(var_1)))`, and

```
df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(var_1), .funs=if_else(!is.na(matches("var_1.")), "Yes", as.character(.)))
```

In both cases, R returns the error message `Error: No tidyselect variables were registered` Could you please write me how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.
[image: Figure]

Comment: `if_else(!is.na(matches("column_names"))` isn't a valid syntax. Can you explain what you are trying to do? Possibly with some data and showing expected output.

Comment: Dear Ronak,Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Dear Ronak,Thank you for your reply. I have a dataframe, retrieved from the medical database. There are variables, corresponding to the question were tests provided or not (let's call them var_1), followed by the results of th tests (let`s call them var_1.1, var_1.2, var_1.3 etc). Logically, "No" s and "NA"s in the var_1 should mean "NA" s in var_1.1, var_1.2, var_1.3 etc, shouldn't they? But some observations, with "No" and "NA" in var_1, have non-missing values in  var_1.1, var_1.2, var_1.3 etc. Therefore, I would like to mutate "No" and "NA" in var_1 into "Yes" for these observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on selected columns.

```
cols <- grep('var_1\\.', names(df))
df$Var1[rowSums(!is.na(df[cols])) > 0] <- 'Yes'
```

Comment: Dear Ronak, thank you very much again. Sorry if I was not very clear. I want to replace "NA" and "No" by "Yes" in the var_1, based on non-missings in var_1.1:var_1.3, keeping variables in var_1.1:var_1.3 as is.

Comment: @JakhongirAlidjanov Can you update your post with a small example and show expected output for it?

Comment: generally saying, I am trying to make more elegant and shorter the following:

`df%>% 
  mutate(var_1=ifelse(!is.na(var_1.1)|
                                   !is.na(var_1.2)|
                                   !is.na(var_1.3)|
                                   !is.na(var_1.4)|
                                   !is.na(var_1.n),
                                   "Yes", as.character(var_1))`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check if this is what you want. It is always better to show an example of data to avoid extending clarification in comments. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Dear Ronak, I have updated the post, adding some clarifications and the image.

Comment: So far, I have found this, non-perfect solution which maybe could be useful for someone: `df %>% select(var_id, var_1, var_1.1:var_1.6) %>%gather("var", "value", var_1.1:var_1.6) %>% mutate(grouped_id = row_number()) %>% mutate(var_1=ifelse(var_1=="No", "No", ifelse(var_1=="Unknown", "Unknown",
                             ifelse(!is.na(value), "Yes", ifelse(var_1=="Yes"&is.na(value), "Yes, but not listed", var_1))))) %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% spread(var, value) %>%select(-grouped_id)`

Comment: If you are still stuck at this I would suggest asking a new question for better visibility and better/faster response.